# Created files/downloaded files go to the top left of the desktop instead of the bottom right

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, icons

I have an issue with my desktop icons on Windows 7. It seems that downloaded files or any files made by programs are sometimes placed on the top left of the desktop, shifting all of my existing desktop icons.

In Windows XP such icons always went to the bottom right. Is there anything I can change that lets you always have everything appear in the bottom right of the desktop icons?

Comment: What are your Sort By and Auto Arrange set to? Right click the desktop and hover over (or click I guess) View and Sort By.

Comment: When you right click on the Desktop and click on View, check to make sure that both Auto arrange icons and Align icons to grid are unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is probably sorting your icons by Name - so if you `right-click` the desktop, and choose `Sort By->Date Modified` it will add the new items after the existing ones.

As for the bottom right corner - I never encountered that behavior.

Another option is to install [Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/index.asp) - It will arrange the constant icons on your desktop in such a way that the non-constant Icons will not interrupt.

Also - consider that a desktop with many icons is usually not that effective for usage, perhaps a **Launcher** can help you.

Comment: Good to know, please mark the question as helpfully. :-)